# Javascript - option api add method not adding to second element

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if am miss understanding the [Option api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add)

Issue : the .add method for an Option element, doesn't add to the second element.

Code example

```
var year = getElement('#by_year'),
year_download = getElement('#download_by_year');

//data.years (just stores the year in a string format)[2018]

//the following will only store in the first option
data.years.forEach(function(y){
    let opt = document.createElement("option");
    let currentTime = new Date();
    opt.value = y.year;
    opt.text = y.year;
    if (currentTime.getFullYear() == y.year){opt.defaultSelected = true;}
    year.add(opt, null);//first select box
    year_download.add(opt, null); // second select box
});
//I solved it like this, but it's redundant
data.years.forEach(function(y){
    let opt = document.createElement("option");
    let currentTime = new Date();
    opt.value = y.year;
    opt.text = y.year;
    if (currentTime.getFullYear() == y.year){opt.defaultSelected = true;}
    year.add(opt, null);
});
data.years.forEach(function(y){
    let opt = document.createElement("option");
    let currentTime = new Date();
    opt.value = y.year;
    opt.text = y.year;
    if (currentTime.getFullYear() == y.year){opt.defaultSelected = true;}
    year_download.add(opt, null);
});
```

Question: why would it only add the option to one and not both?

Answer (score 0):

DOM elements are designed to be concrete objects that can only be "attached" to one place in the DOM tree. They aren't like abstract models that can be added to multiple parents to create multiple segments of a document. You'll need to use a distinct option element for each select. You can use functions to reduce redundancy:

```
function addYearOption(select, year) {
  let opt = document.createElement("option");
  let currentTime = new Date();
  opt.value = y.year;
  opt.text = y.year;
  if (currentTime.getFullYear() == y.year){opt.defaultSelected = true;}
  select.add(opt, null);
}

data.years.forEach(function(y){
  addYearOption(year, y);
  addYearOption(year_download, y);
});
```

Comment: Ah thank you Jacob, for the explanation! This answers my question.